Does colab misunderstand type hints?
The following code produces a colab error marker, but it runs properly.
str1 = 'abcde'
zipped: List[Tuple[int, str]] = [(intgr, ltr) for intgr, ltr in enumerate(str1)]

# This is a clever way to "unzip"
(tuple3, _) = zip(*zipped)
lst3a: list = list(tuple3)

Everything is fine to this point. But the following line produces a colab error mark: a squiggly red line under list(tuple3). (The program runs correctly.)
lst3b: list[int] = list(tuple3)
print(f'{type(lst3a) == type(lst3b)}; {lst3a == lst3b}')  # => True; True

Colab's error explanation is:

Expression of type "list[int | str]" cannot be assigned to declared type "list[int]"

Colab appears confused about the types produced by "unzip."
Or am I missing something?

According to this answer, the type checker in question is Pyright.

It's presumably using some type checker, but the above code (switching out list for List and tuple for Tuple -- please always provide a [mcve]) doesn't producer any errors with either mypy or pyright

Probably related: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/5842

Norepro, even in Colab. Are you sure everything's up to date?

Replacing lst3b: list[int] = list(tuple3) with lst3b: List[int] = list(tuple3) doesn't help.

The question was about colab, not mypy or pyright.

Don't know how to ensure colab is up to date. Doesn't Google do that?
